# Making a mini mic speaker

Tags: amplifier, microphone, speakers

[image]

I’m making a mic speaker circuit with a [PAM8403](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/PAM8403-247318.pdf) amplifier.

The performance wasn't good enough; mic sensitivity wasn't good and it didn't really amplify my voice, so I thought about adding a MAX9814 to amplify my voice.

Will it work if I connect a MAX9814 to the PAM8403 and how will the performance be?

I am using 4.5 V battery and a 3 W speaker.

Answer (score 1):

As we know, sound waves are converted into electrical waves by a microphone, which we refer to as an audio signal. However, the signal produced by a microphone isn't strong enough to be audible through a speaker, even with a speaker amplifier. In this configuration, the amplifier isn't receiving a high enough voltage to properly amplify it to the speaker stage. A microphone typically produces a mic level signal (1 millivolt to 1 volt), whereas the amplifier you are using requires a line-level input signal (100 millivolts to 1.736 volts). Your project needs a preamplifier to overcome this.

Yes, you can use the MAX9814 microphone preamplifier and set the volume of the audio by the gain pin on the module. By connecting gain to GND, you get 40dB (100x) gain; connecting gain to VDD, you get 50dB (316x) gain; by leaving the gain pin unconnected to let it float, you get 60dB (1000x) gain. Here is an image of the MAX9814 module for reference:
[image: MAX9814 module]

In my personal opinion, if you don't require superior audio quality and consistent gain, you could actually build your own discrete preamplifier like in this circuit and connect it to the PAM8403's input.

[image: Discrete preamplifier]

[Link to the schematic](http://www.circuitdiagram.org/microphone-preamp-circuit.html)

Comment: I like this answer! I know it's already in the diagram, and I know this is a very standard electret mic preamp circuit that the other website did not invent either, but could you still link to your source for the circuit you show?

Comment: Thank you; I'm glad it was helpful. Since there wasn't much on the website, I didn't think it mattered, but I figured it's ethically moral behavior to provide resources. Actually, the very same circuit was once discussed on the platform https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/189354/transistor-mic-preamp I tried a very similar circuit and think it would be useful.