# A mini mic speaker circuit

Tags: arduino, microphone, speakers

[image]

I'm making a mic speaker circuit using max9814 and pam8403.

I made the circuit like the picture, but the speaker just makes a long beep and the mic doesn't work.

And, i just tried putting the condenser to max9814 AR and it works if i press both sides of max9814 AR with my hands(maybe some resistance by my hands)
I tried my best to make it fixed the same as i use my hands but it doesn't work.

I also tried to adjust the gain and attack but it doesn't work too.

I want to know how i should solve this problem with putting it on OUT.

I need to make it work good or at least clear.

Comment: What does the Arduino tag has to do with this? Also why you are taking the mic ground from the noisiest possible place - you are sharing a wire with high currents and high noise with low noise signal ground.

Comment: We need schematics of the internal circuits of these modules, especially the amp. If you didn't get them with your purchase, you may need to carefully trace them. And pictures of your setup.

Comment: Related to this earlier closed post: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/695984/making-a-mini-mic-speaker

Comment: I can't help but notice you feed a "5V" pin with 4.5V...

Comment: Did you consider, that it works and you just have an acoustic feedback?

Comment: How did you build the physical circuit? Did you solder wires between them? Built the circuit on a breadboard?

Answer (score 0):

For many circuits, the wiring isn't critical. Here it can be. You don't want power current flowing in the signal lines. See new wiring diagram below.

The amp probably has an AC coupled input so you don't need another cap, the large cap you added may be causing weird issues.

The amp doesn't appear to have enough decoupling caps. Put the 100 uF at the power input to the amp.

As *Jens* mentioned, this circuit will be prone to feedback if you aren't careful. Substitute headphones for the speaker to start.

Reduce the gain to start. Increase it after it is working.

[image]